# Removing certain strings from text with a specific format

Tags: python, regex

What I'm trying to do is remove certain date strings that randomly popup in the text I'm using, the format is like this: `14 Sept 2021` but the day, month and year is dynamic so it can change.

What I have tried is:

```
    def clean_up_answer(answer):
        date_pattern = re.search("(\d{2}[.]+\d{4}[.]+\d{4})", answer)
        if date_pattern is not None and date_pattern != 'None':
            answer = re.sub('(\d{2}[.]+\d{4}[.]+\d{4})', '', answer)
            return answer.strip()
        else:
            return answer.strip()
```

I think regex is best for this but my regex is shaky, from what I can see the above code looks ok but obviously does not remove the specific strings, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you search string only with `digits` and `dots`` but `14 Sept 2021` has string `Sept` which don't have digits. You have to search also letters `[A-Za-z]` or words like `Sept|May|April`, and also spaces between elements. Maybe you should create many separated regex and check them in `for`-loop

Answer (score 0):

Following up on what furas said you need to accommodate the month text in your script.

You also don't need to check if the pattern you want to replace is in the string. `re.sub()` will not make any replacements in your string if it cannot find the pattern to match in the string.

```
import re

def clean_up_answer(answer):
    answer = re.sub('\d+\s\w+\s\d+', '', answer)
    return answer.strip()

test_string = "Today's date is 11 Nov 2022"

print(clean_up_answer(test_string))
# Today's date is
```

The above code will make the replacement if it exists. The regex is \d+ for the digits of the day, \s for the space, \w+ for the text of the month, \s for the second space, and \d+ for the year. Note that by using the + symbol we can also accommodate for when the year is 2 or 4 digits (22 vs. 2022) and when the day is 1 or 2 digits (09 vs. 9).

Hope this helps!